# Visual Studio Code won't recognize variables in CSS file

Tags: css, variables, visual-studio-code

i'm using Visual Studio Code and i have problem vith variables in CSS files, when i type a dollar sign, css file report error and browser won't see changes in file.[image]

Comment: Make sure your file name for your SASS uses `.scss`. Use a compiler to transform your SASS into CSS. Variables may not be able to find each other, but a good compiler will tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define CSS variables. The variable you are looking at is used in SCSS. To use SCSS you need something like [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: red;
}

div {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

body {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

To make VSCode aware of SCSS make sure the file is stored as such (`.scss`). If that still doesn't work set language mode to SCSS. The language mode can be found on the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing a sass syntax, so you need to save your file with (.scss) extension, and as **Sass** is a preprocessor scripting language, you also need a compiler to get a compiled css version like  **live sass compiler extesion in  vscode** to be able to connect the .css file with your index.html file

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to use SCSS ( Sass ) but it seems you didn't install Sass at all or visual studio code needs a plugin for that.
Probably you know what to do now.